# Classes implementing generic interfaces

Tags: c#

### Problem Description

I am struggling to get my generic interfaces to work. I have an `IContainer<TShape>` that takes a list of shapes, where the shapes must implement the `IShape<TPoint>` interface. The `IShape<TPoint>` interface has a list of points, where the points must implement the `IPoint` interface. The part that I am struggling with is the `where` constraint on the `IContainer<TShape>` interface.

The error I'm getting is:

> The type 'TPoint' cannot be used as type parameter 'TPoint' in the
> generic type or method 'IShape'. There is no boxing conversion
> or type parameter conversion from 'TPoint' to
> 'Domain.Entities.IPoint'. [Domain]csharp(CS0314)

### Interfaces

Container interface:

```
public interface IContainer<TShape, TPoint> where TShape : IShape<TPoint>
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public List<TShape<TPoint>> Shapes { get; set; }
}
```

Shape interface:

```
public interface IShape<TPoint> where TPoint : IPoint
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public List<TPoint> Coordinates { get; set; }
}
```

Point interface:

```
public interface IPoint
{
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
}
```

### Models

The way I would like my models to work is:

Container model:

```
public class Container : IContainer<Shape, Point>
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public List<Shape<Point>> Shapes { get; set; }
}
```

Shape model:

```
public class Shape: IShape<Point>
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public List<Point> Coordinates { get; set; }
}
```

Point model:

```
public class Point : IPoint
{
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
}
```

What syntax is needed to make this work?

Comment: Why is `IPoint` needed. Do you have more than one Point implementation?

Comment: @JohnAlexiou - I do. I have a domain model that has a point (for calculations), a web api that has a point (for model binding & transferring between client and server), and a data access layer with a pointDto. To transfer the point between everything I thought I would program to an interface. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue is that on IContainer you are only providing a type constraint for TShape, when IShape also requires a type constraint on TPoint.

Try modifying your IContainer interface to the following:

```
public interface IContainer<TShape, TPoint>
    where TShape : IShape<TPoint>
    where TPoint : IPoint
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public List<TShape<TPoint>> Shapes { get; set; }
}
```